Puppeteer, how to select button which has no id
Very new to puppeteer & javascript, and I have no JSON experience at all.  I'm trying to select the following button:
<button style=SomeColorInfo class=LongListOfClassNames type="button" role="button">
    <span>visible text</span>
</button>

(I have indications that the site already knows it's being scraped, so I'd rather not publicise the URL or specific details of the code unless necessary.)
I can select the button using (a very long) xpath, but this seems risky as it ties my code to the particular structure of the DOM.  Since the page doesn't have many buttons, and the text in the <span> is extremely unlikely to ever change, I'd prefer that the code look for a button with that text.
There's no scrolling or next-page issues to take care of; this page is finite.  I'm just banging my head against a brick wall trying to get the button selected!
I have tried each of the following in turn:
const theB = await page.locator('button');
const theB = await page
    .locator('button')
    .filter(button => button.innerText === 'visible text');
const theB = await page
    .locator('button')
    .filter(button => button.innerText == 'visible text');
const theB = await page
    .locator('button')
    .filter(button => button.innerText = 'visible text');
const theB = await page
    .locator('button')
    .filter(button => button.innerText.startsWith('visible'));
const theB = await page
    .locator('button')
    .filter(button => button.innerText.contains('visible'));
const theB = await page
    .locator('button')
    .filter(button => button.innerHTML.contains('visible'));
const theB = await page.locator('::-p-aria([role="button"])');

Most of these have been inspired by threads in here.  None are working.  Each time I get undefined from console.log(theB.innerHTML);
(In case it makes a difference, the end goal is to click this button.  Since I wasn't managing to achieve that I backed off slightly, to just get it selected and then read out its html.)
Can someone please point me in the right direction of solving this seemingly basic problem?  Many thanks!

If the dupe doesn't work, please provide a complete, runnable [mcve]. Thanks.

It's an easy task for XPath.
You can then use this query to select this button:
For version > 21.11.0, use:
'::-p-xpath(//button[./span="visible text"])'

for versions < 22.*, use:
'//button[./span="visible text"]'

Is it that long this XPath query?

This is the only call I have found that works: page.locator('::-p-xpath(/html/body/div[1]/main/section[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/button[2])').click(); As I said, I don't like the idea of hard-coding the page structure.  If this button happens to be put somewhere else my scraper could be screwed.

Also, have tried your kind suggestions, and it's still not working...

I just tried reducing your first line to const button_selector = '//button'; and even that doesn't work!??!

It's hanging at waitForXPath() (I waited more than a minute).  May I use chat to communicate with you, would that be less public than here and thus I could give you the URL?

Tested my code locally. It works. Will not chat

Well, I appreciate the time you have put into this, thank you :-)

OK, I have followed your instructions to make the MCVE...and I got "page.waitForXPath is not a function" so I replaced that line with await page.waitForSelector(button_selector); and once again, it hangs there. Thank you again for your time, I do appreciate it.

@skiaddict1 This is not a good answer. Avoid XPath which is almost never necessary. Avoid page.waitForXPath and page.$x which were removed from the library many versions ago. Please see the canonical thread which has updated info for this. If the standard clicking/text selection code (likely using p-selectors) doesn't work, then please provide a [mcve], because there could be other issues like iframes, shadow roots or bot blocks preventing you from making this click on your specific site.

Avoid XPath which is almost never necessary What a funny assertion

How is it funny? XPath is basically unnecessary, legacy 1990s style of selection designed for XML. It's ugly, verbose, unreadable and has a ton of footguns, leading to brittle, unmaintainable selection code. It was abused for many years for text selection in Puppeteer, but now there are better native ways to do it. Puppeteer itself is rather unopinionated (even so, it removed all XPath funcs), but sucessor libraries like Playwright actively advise against XPath.

page.locator('button span::-p-text("visible text")') would be preferred here (and actually runs on recent versions of Puppeteer). That said, OP's code should work (and uses the recommended locators), so they probably aren't providing enough details to actually fix this problem. Sending them down a rabbit hole of deprecated functions and outdated, verbose selection strategies is no good.

Great news: I have managed to get an MCVE which successfully clicks the button.  Now I need to figure out why the website won't do it...   Thank you both for your help :-)

@skiaddict1 Good news, but the goal of a MCVE is to reproduce your real problem in a shareable context, so sounds like there's more work to do still. I would check headless/bot blocks, iframes and shadow roots primarily.

@ggorlen Many thanks for the pointers, I will do that.  I understand the primary reason for an MCVE, but since this one works it also gives me something to compare my code with -- instead of simply stumbling around in the dark!  Thanks again :-)
